# Open native iOS audio output destination picker in-app

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I would like to open iOS' native audio destination picker UI inside of my application (pictured below). Is there a way to do this with `AVAudioSession`?

[image: iOS Native Audio Output Picker]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the control I was looking for: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avroutepickerview. It appears on screen as a button (with the default AirPlay 2 icon) and handles all of the logic for you.

Example

```
import AVKit

let audioPicker = AVRoutePickerView(frame: ...)
addSubview(audioPicker)
```

You can subscribe to audio route updates with the following:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: ...), name: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: is there any way to present that view programmatically?